# Intel XDK IoT edition node js -IoT app upload location on the Galileo Gen 2 Board

Tags: node.js, intel-xdk, intel-galileo

Where does the node js files of any IoT project get uploaded by the daemon in the galileo board while using intel xdk iot edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find your project files uploaded from Intel XDK IoT Edition in the **.node_app_slot** folder.

When you connect to the Intel Galileo Gen 2 board via SSH or serial connection, you can run the `ls -al` command to view the folder in the current directory.